# Using reflection, is there a way to load a .NET type with generic parameters without having to append the number of them to the name?

Tags: .net, reflection

I am working on my own language and for the sake of .NET interop I've been using the Reflection methods to query the .NET types and method signatures.

```
open System
let asm = Reflection.Assembly.Load("mscorlib")
let dic = asm.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2")
```

The above is how I would load the type of Dictionary directly from `mscorlib`. Note that unlike in standard code, the `2` at the end separated by the grave character is necessary.

Since C# and F# do not require specifying the number of generic parameters as a part of the name, I've been wondering whether there is a better way of doing this?

This is awkward because right now, I have to write out the full name in my language's code as well.

Comment: sure they do. If you use reflection in C# you still need it, or just from the language it is taken from the number of generic parameters: Dictionary<a,b>

Comment: F# infers them though, meaning it knows the number of generic params just from the name. I wonder how it does that. Is it even possible for a type to have the same name, but different number of generic params? Like `Dictionary``2` and `Dictionary``3` for example?

Comment: Yes, absolutely - take `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` etc. Ditto `Tuple`, `Func`, `ValueTuple`, `IList` vs `IList<T>` etc.

Comment: "F# infers them though, meaning it knows the number of generic params just from the name" - I don't believe that's true. I believe it infers them based on the context as well as the name. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to work with types where there *are* multiple generic arities.

Comment: This is a good point. I guess then I have my answer in this. Since my language does propagation and not inference, I will have to write out the full name or do some trickery to delay the load until I have the generic arguments given. Thanks.